# Entity Framework my DB Context does not have connection when Reference in other Project

Tags: entity-framework-5

So here is my problem Guys

In my Solution,

1. I have ORM Class Liberary where I've added EntityFramework 5 (so has .edmx containing Context.tt
   Designer.cs, edmx.diagram and .tt) files.. So far so good
2. And I have Project called Repositories and has reference of ORM project above.
3. In HeaderRepository class of Repositories Project, when I write following code,

   using(UFPEntities ufpEntities = new UFPEntities())
   {
   try{
   Header header = ufpEntities.Headers.Single(x => x.VendorId == id);
   }catche(Exception e)
   {
   }
   }
   Note: intellisense works fine COMPILER DOES NOT GIVE ERROR while writing above code, it happens at Run time

But, I get "No connection string named 'UFPEntities' could be found in the application config file."

App.config is in ORM Project, not in Repository Project where I am dealing with Data as Above.

Can you please help me so that I can CREATE MY MODEL class (such as Header) from Repository Project? or What I am doing wrong so it gives me Exceptions?

Thx in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string must be in config of entry assembly - it is either web.config for web application or app.config for executable or unit test library. App.config for arbitrary library which is just referenced by executed code is completely ignored.

Comment: You are right Ladislav Mrnka, Connection String must be in the Calling Application where the Request was initiated from, in this Case Web.config.